Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal. No entiendo
Hola no entiendo porque me da ese error. Estoy practicando Java en eclipse pero de un tiempo para aca NADA de lo que quiero hacer compila. Ya he revisado las librerias y nada, sigue igual. Gracias por la ayuda


El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Hombre, ahí te sale un paquete marcado con un aspa roja de error. Eso no es buena señal. ¿Qué error te indica? Si el proyecto no puede recompilarse automáticamente por algo, no te va a generar los .class y siempre te va a salir eso de ClassNotFoundException.

Como dice Rubio, la marca roja indica una clase con errores de compilcación, verifica eso, en la imagen no se alcanza a ver quien tiene el error. Luego de corregir, recompila, y revisa si saltan más errores. Ahi al menos dice graficos.creandoMarcos

Creo que olvidaste compilar el código

Hola Cesar, bienvenido, esto es algo que me ha pasado en varias ocaciones, no se el origen del problema, pero lo solucioné cambiando (con refactor) el nombre de la clase, y el nombre del .java, volviendo a compilar... es solo para probar, no hay certeza de que funcione.

Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el código y mensajes de error deben publicarse como texto y no como imágenes.
